# CheckBox always returns null in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

When clicking on the checkbox, form is submitted using jQuery, but checkbox always return null.

I have the following Razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HumanResource", new { type = ViewBag.CurrentType }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
 <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" for="Filter">
        @Html.CheckBox("Filter", new { @class = "custom-control-input" })
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        Choose
 </label>
}

// Scripts

<script>
$('#form1 :checkbox').change(function() {
            $("#form1").submit();
   });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FormCollection fc,int? Filter)
{
    // leftFilter is always null
}
```

Comment: Checkbox submits boolean, not an int

Comment: @Andrei I didn't have problem regarding if it's boolean or not, after I changed theme's files, that's happened.

Comment: That is exactly your problem, when model binder cannot parse the value it sets variable to null instead. 'true' and 'false' cannot be parse to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the form is submitted, the browser will send either `true` or `false` for `filter` input in form data, to the form `action` URL( the action method which handles the form submit). You are using a nullable int(`int?`) as the parameter to accept the value of `filter`. The model binder cannot map a boolean value to a nullable int. How does it know what value to assign in the numeric parameter for true /false ? It can map the incoming boolean value to only a boolean parameter.

So change your parameter type to `bool`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index4(FormCollection fc, bool filter)
{
    //to so : return something
}
```

Now when the form is submitted, the `filter` parameter will be populated with a value.

Suggestion: Submitting a form when user clicks on the checkbox seems like a bad user experience IMHO, what if user wants to change ? How about adding a separate "search" button and submit the form when user clicks on that after making the checkbox selections ? Or perhaps consider some client side/ajax sort of filtering.

Comment: I agree with @Shyju about the checkbox being used for submitting the form. It's bad UX.